# To solve $y'=\frac{\cos y+y\cos x}{x\sin y-\sin x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'(x)=\frac{\cos (y(x))+y(x) \cos (x)}{x \sin (y(x))-\sin (x)}$$
I am self-learning the differential equation from a textbook and I need some help with above equation. I learned I-factor (for 1st order linear ODE), Bernoulli's, and Riccati's. So the problem should be solved by them. The book doesn't have any examples using trig functions.

I tried wolfram alpha but the website could not give me "step-by-step". Does anyone know why? Wolfram Alpha never had this problem where it could not give "step-by-step".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y'(x)=\frac{\cos (y(x))+y(x) \cos (x)}{x \sin (y(x))-\sin (x)}$$

we can re-write as 
$$
x \sin (y(x))y'-\sin (x)y' = -x\frac{d}{dx}\cos (y(x)) -\sin(x)y'=\cos (y(x))+y(x) \cos (x)
$$
collecting similar terms(by inspection that is)
$$
-x\frac{d}{dx}\cos (y(x))-\cos(y(x)) = -\frac{d}{dx}x\cos(y(x))
= \sin(x)y' + y(x)\cos(x) = \frac{d}{dx}y\sin(x)
$$
or
$$
-\frac{d}{dx}x\cos(y(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}y\sin(x)
$$

proceed :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer. Sorry for asking about this again so late but would mind explaining to me about this? I actually couldn't understand how you could get

xsin(y)y' becomes -x(d/dx)cos(y)

Comment: I meant how you could get -x(d/dx)cos(y) from xsin(y)y'. I understand that d/dx(sin(y)) is -cos(y) but this is dy/dx in the term... Sorry if this too basic question. >:O

Comment: Not a problem. The reason comes from how you take the derivative implicitly (I forget the actual terminology from time to time) but $$\frac{d}{dx}f(y) = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{df}{dy}$$ can you see how I got to that conclusion in the answer?

Comment: Thank you! I would have never thought of doing it that way. One question, if I did an integration to find f, wouldn't it be: $$ \[Integral]x sin(y) \[DifferentialD]y=-x cos(y) + Subscript[c, 1] $$ Should you have a c as a result of your integration?

Comment: No worries. The resulting answer is $$-x\cos(y) = y \sin x + C_1$$.

Comment: So how do we know if we can disregard c from integrations? I was stuck on this question and because I couldn't understand how you did it, I had to solve it on my own. I don't know if it is right though. What I did was rearrange to make the equation = 0 $$ -\cos (y(x))-y(x) \cos (x)+\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x} (x \sin (y(x))-\sin (x))=0 $$ and I found out that the problem can be solved through the Exact Solution because $ y \sin -x \cos $.

Comment: Aw man, my latex is bad. Sorry. I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: I meant to say I solved through Exact Solution because $\sin (y)-\cos (x)$ did I solve it wrong?

Comment: I am sorry I am not really understanding how you mean exact solution? by change of variables?

Comment: Oh that's what my textbook called it. If we can find an equation to be an exact equation then the solution is f(x,y) = c. So in this case if we let $$P(x,y) = -y cos(x)-cos(y)$$ $$Q(x,y) = x sin(y)-sin(x)$$. Then we can see that this is an exact equation because $$\partial P(x,y)/\partial y= \sin (y) - \cos (x) =\partial Q(x,y)/\partial x$$ So if this is true, we can find $$frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$$ $$\f(x,y)=\int ((-y) \cos(x))- \cos(y) \, dx = g (y) - y\sin (x) + x (-\cos (y))$$

Comment: And we differentiate f(x,y) with respect to y to get g(y) and plug that equation back to Q(x,y) and in the end I end up with $$-cos(y)x - y (sin(x)) = c_ 1$$

I really appreciate you helping me. :)

Comment: @jameslee that looks like a nice solution. Write it up as an answer here. Having different methods is always better. :) great stuff. Ps I will check it properly when you write it up.